# Magento: which block is unsing in Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController?

Tags: magento

**The main aim is to find where to generate left tag block for new product page. And to modify it.**

To get it I'm trying to understand which block is running in case the product is new?

In this code I print out name block.

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
//...
    /**
     * Create new product page
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
         //...

         $this->loadLayout(array(
                'default',
                strtolower($this->getFullActionName()),
                'adminhtml_catalog_product_'.$product->getTypeId() . $_additionalLayoutPart
         ));

         // echo adminhtml_catalog_product_new
         echo 'adminhtml_catalog_product_'.$product->getTypeId() . $_additionalLayoutPart;
         //...
    }
//...
}
```

Find out this block in catalog.xml:

```
 <adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <!-- ... -->
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs" name="product_tabs"></block>
    </reference>
    <!-- ... -->
</adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
```

In the following step I found block model:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs { /**
     * Initialize Tabs
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    { 
        die("debug label");
        //....
    }

    // ... 
}
```

refresh page and ... nothing happaned.
It seems there is not block that we're searching for...which one then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the layout xml says `adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs`, then it is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs` you should be looking for, not `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs`.

Secondly, I think it is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs_Configurable` which controls the tabs if you are creating a new configurable product.

Comment: oh damn. Too much debuged it) Thanks a lot!